# AppSync query resolver: are expressionNames and expressionValues necessary?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-query

AppSync doc says that `expressionNames` and `expressionValues` are optional fields, but they are always populated by code generation. First question, should they be included as a best practice when working with DynamoDB? If so, why?

**AppSync resolver for a query on the partition key:**

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Query",
    "query": {
        "expression": "#partitionKey = :partitionKey",
        "expressionNames": {
            "#partitionKey": "partitionKey"
        },
        "expressionValues": {
            ":partitionKey": {
                "S": "${ctx.args.partitionKey}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second question, what exactly is the layman translation of the `expression` field here in the code above? What exactly is that statement telling DynamoDB to do? What is the use of the `#` in `"expression": "#partitionKey = :partitionKey"` and are the expression names and values just formatting safeguards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me answer your second question first:

### expressionNames

`expressionNames` are used for interpolation. What this means is after interpolation, this filter expression object:

```
"expression": "#partitionKey = :value",
"expressionNames": {
    "#partitionKey": "id"
}
```

will be transformed to:

```
"expression": "id = :value",
```

the `#partitionKey` acts as a placeholder for your column name `id`. `'#'` happens to be the delimiter.

#### But why?

`expressionNames` are necessary because certain [keywords are reserved by DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html), meaning you can't use these words inside a DynamoDB expression.

### expressionValues

When you need to compare anything in a DynamoDB expression, you will need also to use a substitute for the actual value using a placeholder, because the DynamoDB typed value is a complex object.

In the following example:

```
"expression": "myKey = :partitionKey",
"expressionValues": {
    ":partitionKey": {
        "S": "123"
    }
}
```

`:partitionKey` is the placeholder for the complex value

```
{
    "S": "123"
}
```

`':'` is the different delimiter that tells DynamoDB to use the `expressionValues` map when replacing.

### Why are `expressionNames` and `expressionValues` always used by code generation?

It is just simpler for the code generation logic to always use `expressionNames` and `expressionValues` because there is no need to have two code paths for reserved/non-reserved DynamoDB words. Using `expressionNames` will always prevent collisions!

Comment: Hey Tinou. Would you be able to assist here please?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929031/how-do-i-use-a-global-secondary-index-to-get-the-id-of-a-user-in-my-table